# is possible to run code asynchronously in ContinueWith(), when ContinueWith uses FromCurrentSynchronizationContext TaskScheduler?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, task, continuewith

Is possible to somehow force action calcData to run asynchronously in ContinueWith?

```
Action loadData = () => { Thread.Sleep(200); Console.WriteLine("Used thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); /* Load data from DB*/ };
Action showData = () => { Thread.Sleep(100); Console.WriteLine("Used thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); /* Show data */ };
Action calcData = () => { Thread.Sleep(100); Console.WriteLine("Used thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); /* Calculate some fields*/ };

var task1 = new Task(loadData);

task1.Start();
task1.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
{
    showData();

    var task2 = new Task(calcData);

    task2.Start();
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Output:

```
Used thread: 18
Used thread: 1
Used thread: 1
```